# How to make a list without quotes from string? python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a program in which i input a string then make it into list and then use list.count. To do this i need list without colons.

```
a=("44, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ")
a=[a]
print(a)
-> ['44, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ']
```

but i want this:

```
[44, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

i tried this:

```
b=map(int, a)
print(b)
```

but then get this ->

```
<map object at 0x00537810>
```

and don't know what to do next

Comment: Read: [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: You can use `split` or `list(ast.literal_eval(a))`. Mapping `int` to `a` won't give you a list and won't work either because `,` can't be converted to `int`

Answer (score 4):

It's even easier than that:

```
>>> a=("44, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ")
>>> my_list = [int(s) for s in a.split(", ")]
>>> my_list
[44, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```